# Android can ACTION_SEND be used to call a Service

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-service

I've successfully being able to use the ACTION_SEND intent which displays my application in the list when the share button is pressed in the gallery. My app basically sends the selected picture to my computer and no further input form the user is required. Rather than starting my app when selected in the list which is an unnecessary step is it possible to pass the data to my own service which sends the picture and avoid starting my app?

If not what other options do I have? Start my app, sent the picture and close the activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Rather than starting my app when selected in the list which is an unnecessary step is it possible to pass the data to my own service which sends the picture and avoid starting my app?

`ACTION_SEND` is used for starting activities, not services -- sorry.

> If not what other options do I have? Start my app, sent the picture and close the activity?

Sounds reasonable. If you do all of that in `onCreate()`, call `finish()`, and never call `setContentView()`, nothing will be shown to the user.

Comment: at least on the few devices i've tested, the screen will flash even with a `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` activity, even if `setContentView()` is never called and the activity finishes in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman: I use it a lot, with no blinks that I can discern. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkMapless, to pick three.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Could you explain why "ACTION_SEND is used for starting activities, not services" ? I would be grateful for any doc proving that or the source code.

Comment: @LiMar: When your read the documentation for `ACTION_SEND`, what did you find? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND